# display pdf from url with webview under buttonclick

Tags: android, pdf, webview

Hi I want to add my pdf file from url. When I add a few button and put in webview under onclick my project didnt work. but I put webview under oncreate method it is working good. is it necessery to create java.class every pdf file? isnt it possible add some button like me? I set webview like below but it doesnt work what is mistake thanks:

```
public class MainActivity extends AppCompatActivity {
WebView webview;
ProgressBar progressbar;
Button ahi, edi, ravm, ard, ox, cr;

@Override
protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
    super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
    setContentView(R.layout.activity_main);
    ahi = (Button) findViewById(R.id.ahi);
    ravm = (Button) findViewById(R.id.ravm);
    edi = (Button) findViewById(R.id.edi);
    cr = (Button) findViewById(R.id.cr);
    ard = (Button) findViewById(R.id.ard);
    ox = (Button) findViewById(R.id.ox);
    webview = (WebView) findViewById(R.id.webview);
    progressbar = (ProgressBar) findViewById(R.id.progressbar);
    webview.getSettings().setJavaScriptEnabled(true);

    ard.setOnClickListener(new View.OnClickListener() {
        public void onClick(View v) {

            String filename = "http://www3.nd.edu/~cpoellab/teaching/cse40816/android_tutorial.pdf";
            webview.loadUrl("http://docs.google.com/gview?embedded=true&url=" + filename);

            webview.setWebViewClient(new WebViewClient() {

                public void onPageFinished(WebView view, String url) {
                    // do your stuff here
                    progressbar.setVisibility(View.GONE);
                }
            });
        }
    });
    ox.setOnClickListener(new View.OnClickListener() {
        public void onClick(View v) {

            String filename = "http://www3.nd.edu/~cpoellab/teaching/cse40816/android_tutorial.pdf";
            webview.loadUrl("http://docs.google.com/gview?embedded=true&url=" + filename);

            webview.setWebViewClient(new WebViewClient() {

                public void onPageFinished(WebView view, String url) {
                    // do your stuff here
                    progressbar.setVisibility(View.GONE);
                }
            });
        }
    });

    ahi.setOnClickListener(new View.OnClickListener() {
        public void onClick(View v) {

            String filename = "http://www3.nd.edu/~cpoellab/teaching/cse40816/android_tutorial.pdf";
            webview.loadUrl("http://docs.google.com/gview?embedded=true&url=" + filename);

            webview.setWebViewClient(new WebViewClient() {

                public void onPageFinished(WebView view, String url) {
                    // do your stuff here
                    progressbar.setVisibility(View.GONE);
                }
            });
        }
    });
    edi.setOnClickListener(new View.OnClickListener() {
        public void onClick(View v) {

            String filename = "http://www3.nd.edu/~cpoellab/teaching/cse40816/android_tutorial.pdf";
            webview.loadUrl("http://docs.google.com/gview?embedded=true&url=" + filename);

            webview.setWebViewClient(new WebViewClient() {

                public void onPageFinished(WebView view, String url) {
                    // do your stuff here
                    progressbar.setVisibility(View.GONE);
                }
            });
        }
    });
    ravm.setOnClickListener(new View.OnClickListener() {
        public void onClick(View v) {

            String filename = "http://www3.nd.edu/~cpoellab/teaching/cse40816/android_tutorial.pdf";
            webview.loadUrl("http://docs.google.com/gview?embedded=true&url=" + filename);

            webview.setWebViewClient(new WebViewClient() {

                public void onPageFinished(WebView view, String url) {
                    // do your stuff here
                    progressbar.setVisibility(View.GONE);
                }
            });
        }
    });
    cr.setOnClickListener(new View.OnClickListener() {
        public void onClick(View v) {

            String filename = "http://www3.nd.edu/~cpoellab/teaching/cse40816/android_tutorial.pdf";
            webview.loadUrl("http://docs.google.com/gview?embedded=true&url=" + filename);

            webview.setWebViewClient(new WebViewClient() {

                public void onPageFinished(WebView view, String url) {
                    // do your stuff here
                    progressbar.setVisibility(View.GONE);
                }
            });
        }
    });
}
```

I mean when I set codes below it is work good. but I want to put in under buttonclick as upper it is not work. How could I set my upper codes?

```
public class giris extends AppCompatActivity {
 WebView webview;
ProgressBar progressbar;
@Override
protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
    super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
    setContentView(R.layout.activity_giris);
    webview = (WebView)findViewById(R.id.webview);
    progressbar = (ProgressBar) findViewById(R.id.progressbar);
    webview.getSettings().setJavaScriptEnabled(true);
        String filename = "http://www3.nd.edu/~cpoellab/teaching/cse40816/android_tutorial.pdf";
    webview.loadUrl("http://docs.google.com/gview?embedded=true&url=" + filename);
    //String filename ="https://interactivepdf.uniflip.com/2/34834/312285/pub/document.pdf";
    //webview.loadUrl("http://docs.google.com/gview?embedded=true&url=" + filename);
    webview.setWebViewClient(new WebViewClient() {

        public void onPageFinished(WebView view, String url) {
            // do your stuff here
            progressbar.setVisibility(View.GONE);
        }
    });

}
```

Comment: You are not displaying a pdf. You are displaying html as that google service delivers you html for a pdf.

Comment: so what? what can I do? could you help me? why I couldnt add pdf url link under button click?

Comment: You said something about onCreate(). What exactly? And where is that code? And why code for six buttons? They behave all the same dont they?

Comment: sorry, I mean I only display pdf file after buttonclick events. So ı have six buttons and when I put the codes under buttonclick as my questions, my apps dont work. but when I remove buttons from my java files it works good.But I have to use some buttons what is mistake my codes thanks your interest.

Comment: When you remove the buttons then you load in onCreate? You can have code in onCreate and in OnClick at the same time. So try that. And does it only happen with six buttons? You problem is unclear.

Comment: I mean when I set codes below it is work good. but I want to put in under buttonclick as my question    super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
        setContentView(R.layout.activity_giris);
        webview = (WebView)findViewById(R.id.webview);
        progressbar = (ProgressBar) findViewById(R.id.progressbar);
        webview.getSettings().setJavaScriptEnabled(true);
   String filename = "http://www3.nd.edu/~cpoellab/teaching/cse40816/android_tutorial.pdf";
        webview.loadUrl("http://docs.google.com/gview?embedded=true&url=" + filename);

Comment: Please put that code in an extra code block in your post. Do you want us to read that unreadable code?

Comment: ok I added new code blocks what my apps working good.

Comment: Now if you add one button to the last onCreate() ... only one button... then what happens?

Comment: I want to add 6 button and  every button goes another pdf file from url.. there is no button in which my last code block. and it is good working.  but when I put six button in which my first code block it is not working.

Comment: `there is no button in which my last code block. `. Yes. I know. Thats why i asked you to add one. Ar you unwilling ? Or dont you understand English?

Comment: `6 button and every button goes another pdf file from url` At the moment you use the same pdf file for all. So what is going on?

Comment: :) hey maaan are you kidding me? what do you want to do. do you really know anything about this isue. if you help me thanks alot..